# Finding the area of a triangle from subareas

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

A triangle is being divided by two lines. The newly created smaller triangles have the area shown in the picture. What is the area of the whole triangle?

[image]

**My progress so far:**
The two triangles $EJB$ and $BJC$ share the line $BJ$. Additionally, $EJ$ and $JC$ share the same height. Given this and the fact that the area of $EJB$ and $BJC$ are the same, $EJ$ and $JC$ must be of the same length. Therefore, $EJB$ and $BJC$ must be congruent. Am I right so far, and if so, where do I go from here?

Comment: Did you try to use the formulas for the area ($S = \frac 12 bc \sin A = \frac 12 ab \sin C = \frac 12 ac \sin B$) in the smaller triangles and explore the congruent sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that $EJ$ and $JC$ have the same length. However, this doesn't imply that $EJB$ and $BJC$ are congruent triangles.

Hint: For the next step, connect points $E$ and $K$ with segment $EK$, and deduce that triangles $EJK$ and $KJC$ have the same area. This leaves one triangle whose area you need to determine. Say the area of this remaining triangle is $y$. Look at the two sets of triangles whose bases are $AE$ and $EB$. Now explain why the following equation is true:
$$
\frac y{1+3}=\frac{y+1 +1}{3 + 3}
$$